# Botframework second ChoiceSet value upon first ChoiceSet selection

Tags: c#, botframework

got a question regarding Botframework Choiceset/Dropdown.

I need the second Choiceset value to change upon the selection of First Choiceset value. Is it possible to do it in botframework? Something like eventchange of the first Choiceset value.

I know how to create the ChoiceSet but cannot figure out how to detect the event of the first Choiceset selection.

Thanks.

Comment: `I need the second Choiceset value to change upon the selection of First Choiceset value.` Do you want to implement cascading Choiceset(s)? By default, botframework and channels seem not provide this functionality, if you are embed your bot in website via webchat, you can try to achieve it on JavaScript client.

Comment: @FeiHan What i want to achieve is that based on the first dropdown value selected, i need to change the second dropdown value. Is it the same as the 1 you mentioned? Cascading Choiceset?

Comment: `What i want to achieve is that based on the first dropdown value, i need to change the second dropdown value.` I mentioned same thing, dynamically updating the selection of the second Choiceset based on the first Choiceset value, as far as I know, bot and channels do not provide this functionality.

Comment: Are you using web chat channel? If yes, you could try to achieve the requirement via JavaScript in your web page.

Comment: Yup. im using WebChat channel. Not really comfortable with Javascript but will try it out. How do i approach it? Do i still create the choiceset in the adaptive card and check the value of the first dropdown, change accordingly of the second dropdown value using Javascript?

Comment: `Do i still create the choiceset in the adaptive card and check the value of the first dropdown, change accordingly of the second dropdown value using Javascript?` Yes, you can do that. Besides, please refer to my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the second Choiceset value to change upon the selection of First Choiceset value. Is it possible to do it in botframework? Something like eventchange of the first Choiceset value.

The first approach: you can try to show the first `Input.ChoiceSet` in an adaptive card, after user select one option and send the selection back to your bot, you can dynamically populate `Choices` property of the second `Input.ChoiceSet` and show it in another adaptive card.

> im using WebChat channel.

The second approach: you embed webchat in website(s), as I mentioned in comment, you can try to achieve the requirement on JavaScript client side.

```
<script>
    var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: '{directline_secret_here}' });

    var userinfo = { id: '{user_id_here}'};

    BotChat.App({
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: userinfo,
        bot: { id: '{bot_id_here}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));


    botConnection.activity$
        .filter(activity => activity.type === "message")
        .subscribe(activity => BindOnChangeEventToSelect(activity));

    function BindOnChangeEventToSelect(activity) {

        //Attach a handler to 'change' event of <select> element
        $("select.ac-multichoiceInput:nth-of-type(2n+1)").on("change", function () {
            $(this).siblings("select").val($(this).val());
        }); 
    }
</script>
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: Tqvm. Will try to apply